# Rails 3-"Couldn't find [model] without an ID" problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
Couldn't find Submission without an ID
```

This problem has haunted me for last few days, and I can't seem to fix it. 
This problem occurs when I try to create an Emailinterest object in the app.

I have two models.

- Submission
- Emailinterest

For every submission, there can be several emailinterest, but emailinterest cannot exist

**C:\Rails\actuirl5\app\controllers\emailinterests_controller.rb**

submission_id actually a member of emailinterest object. submission_id is suppose to contain the ID value of submission object.

```
def create
    @emailinterest = Emailinterest.new(params[:emailinterest])
    @submission = Submission.find(params[:submission_id])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @emailinterest.save
            Notifier.emailinterest_notification(@emailinterest, @submission).deliver
            format.html { redirect_to(@emailinterest, :notice => 'Email was successfully sent!') }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @emailinterest, :status => :created, :location => @emailinterest }
        else
            format.html { render :action => "new" }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @emailinterest.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

**C:\Rails\actuirl5\app\views\submissions\show.html.erb**

```
....

<%= render :partial=>"form_new_emailinterest", :locals=>{:emailinterest=>Emailinterest.new(:submission_id=>@submission.id)} %>
```

**C:\Rails\actuirl5\app\views\submissions**

```
<%= form_for(emailinterest) do |f| %>

    <%= hidden_field :submission_id, :value => @submission.id %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :sender_email %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :sender_email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :sender_email_content %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :sender_email_content %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

---

## FIX

**C:\Rails\actuirl5\app\controllers\emailinterests_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @emailinterest = Emailinterest.new(params[:emailinterest])
    @submission = Submission.find(params[:submission_id])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @emailinterest.save
            Notifier.emailinterest_notification(@emailinterest, @submission).deliver
            format.html { redirect_to(@emailinterest, :notice => 'Email was successfully sent!') }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @emailinterest, :status => :created, :location => @emailinterest }
        else
            format.html { render :action => "new" }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @emailinterest.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

**C:\Rails\actuirl5\app\views\submissions_form_new_emailinterest.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(emailinterest) do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :submission_id, value = @submission.id %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :sender_email %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :sender_email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :sender_email_content %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :sender_email_content %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**C:\Rails\actuirl5\app\views\submissions\show.html.erb**

```
<%= render :partial=>"form_new_emailinterest", :locals=>{:emailinterest=>Emailinterest.new} %>
```

Comment: Try this: `@submission = Submission.find(params[:emailinterest][:submission_id])`

Comment: `Couldn't find Submission without an ID` Still got this error.

Comment: Show the `params` being received by the server. Looks the  `submission_id` being passed to `Submission.find` is `nil`.

Comment: "Show the params being received by the server." What's a quick way of doing this?

Comment: do `tail log/development.log` and look for the request -- the parameter hash is written after each action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you have set @submission in your show action this should work:

```
<%= hidden_field :submission_id, :value => emailinterest.submission_id %>
```

and then

```
@submission = Submission.find(params[:emailinterest][:submission_id])
```

You cannot access instance variables like @submission in a partials. This is why you have the option :locals.

Comment: By emailinterest.submission.id, you mean emailinterest.submission_id?

`Couldn't find Submission without an ID` I got this error again.

Comment: Yeah you are right submission_id. Then check the following. Check if @submission.id actually exists in your show right before your render partial. If it exists check if you can still access it via emailinterest.submission_id in your partial. (Just put <%= %> around it) If that is still the case put "puts params.inspect" in your controller and check the log.